# Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

on my wordpress site, since I installed the ACF plugin, I am now getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined.

My jQuery has stopped working. Please help

Comment: what is the version of ACF and WP?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same issue

Comment: In which page you get the error? Also, could you post your WP installation details? Plugins, theme, WP version, etc.